# How to define a SPIN rule?

Tags: sparql, allegrograph, spin-rdf

I am using AllegroGraph 4.4. I have their sample database input regarding the Kennedy family tree. I have copied an example from their tutorials on SPIN. Here it is:

```lisp
(ag.spin:register-spin-function  
!ex:age  
"prefix kennedy: <http://www.franz.com/simple#>  
 prefix xs: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>  
 select ( (2011 - xs:int(?birthYear)) as ?age ) {  
   ?who kennedy:birth-year ?birthYear .  
 }"  
'(?who))
```

The problem is that I do not know *where* and *how* to register this function. I've tried the WebView, but I get this error:

```
Non-symbol element !ex:age in binding list.
```

Why do I keep getting this error?

Where should I define the rule?

Answer (score 1):

The code is Common Lisp code that should be part of a source file, or evaluated in the REPL. The error you are getting,  ”Non-symbol element !ex:age in binding list” seems to indicate that the system is choking while trying to process `!ex:age`.  Does executing the [setup from the example](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/spin.html#header2-35) first help?  The first line and last lines, `(enable-!-reader)`, and `(register-namespace "ex" "http://franz.examples#")`, seem like what you would need in order to get `!ex:age` to be read properly.

```
(enable-!-reader)  
(enable-print-decoded t)  
(create-triple-store "kennedy")  
(load-ntriples "kennedy.ntriples")  
(register-namespace "kennedy" "http://www.franz.com/simple#")  
(register-namespace "ex" "http://franz.examples#")
```